# How did the introduction of artificial light changed the life cycle of a plant?

Tags: plant-physiology, circadian-rhythms

Plants in urbanized areas are constantly exposed to artificial light after sunset. In their natural habitat there is a more distinct day and night cycle.

Since light is an important factor in a plant life cycle, I wonder if the introduction of the artificial light forces any changes in the life cycle of plants in urbanized areas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to this [study](http://rstb.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/370/1667/20140131), artificial lighting similar to that provided by streetlights in the UK can *reduce* flowering in at least one plant, which also affects the aphids that feed on it.

This [article](https://www.extension.purdue.edu/extmedia/fnr/fnr-faq-17.pdf) discusses it in more general terms - night lighting doesn't affect photosynthesis, but can affect the length of day/night perceived by plants and alter growth accordingly. There are two examples given of how it is harmful:

- Young trees grow longer and don't enter dormancy, making them increasingly susceptible to cold temperatures.
- The stomatal pores of leaves remain open longer, making some trees more susceptible to pollution and water stress.